# Parallelize reassignment of elements in large array

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've got a numpy array, `chop_preds`, that is very large (~10 million elements) that needs to be modified such that it contains values of 1.0, 0.5, or 0 (see below).

How can I parallelize this reassignment?

```
chop_preds=chop_preds.flatten()

for k in range(len(chop_preds)):
    if(chop_preds[k]>=0.4):
        chop_preds[k]=1.0 
    elif(chop_preds[k]<0.1):
        chop_preds[k]=0 
    else:
        chop_preds[k]=0.5 

my_sum=np.sum(chop_preds)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, reading and then assigning an integer to each element of a 10M element array runs in 1.2s serially on my macbook. Depending on your use case there may be no reason to bother.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only a small part of a larger code, and this part needs to be repeated for many different `chop_preds`.  This snippet, once repeated, takes 7 of the 8 minutes my program takes to run, and I haven't scaled it up yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `chop_preds` is already a `numpy` array, you can use:

```
chop_preds_flat = chop_preds.flatten()
chop_preds = 0.5 * np.ones_like(chop_preds_flat)
chop_preds[chop_preds_flat >= 0.4] = 1.
chop_preds[chop_preds_flat < 0.1] = 0.

my_sum = chop_preds.sum()
```

Or, if you really only need the sum, use [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) on those selections:

```
my_sum = 0.5 * np.count_nonzero((chop_preds_flat >= 0.1) & (chop_preds_flat < 0.4))
my_sum += np.count_nonzero(chop_preds_flat >= 0.4)
```

Even simpler, but a bit harder to read:

```
my_sum = ((chop_preds_flat >= 0.4) + 0.5 * ((chop_preds_flat >= 0.1) & (chop_preds_flat < 0.4))).sum()
```

Between those three ways, `numpy.count_nonzero` seems to be the fastest:

[image]

For comparison, your original implementation takes about 0.2 seconds for the last input on that plot, so about 20 times longer than the worst `numpy` implementation (and about 100 times longer than the fastest).

Comment: This is dramatically faster!  Clever!

Answer (score 3):

For multi processing, you can use the "pathos"  ([github page](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/pathos/multiprocessing.py)) package that you can install using pip.

In your case, I would try something like this:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

def chopper(value):
  if(value >= 0.4):
     value = 1.0 
  elif(value < 0.1):
    value = 0 
  else:
    value = 0.5
  return

chop_preds = chop_preds.flatten()
#-------------------------------------------------------------SETUP
pass;                                                         from zmq import Stopwatch; aClock = Stopwatch(); aPrintMASK = "The Critical Section took {0: > 12d} [us] to complete on [{1: >12d}] sized array"
#-------------------------------------------------------------SECTION-TO-TEST:
pass;                                                         aClock.start()
#----------------<_!_>
myPool = Pool(8)                   # assuming you have an 8 cpu cores machines
myPool.map(chopper,chop_preds)
#----------------<_!_>
pass;                                                         D = aClock.stop()
pass;                                                         print aPrintMASK.format( D, chop_preds.shape[0] )
#-------------------------------------------------------------SECTION-TO-TEST.End
```

Comment: Hope you would not mind the injected [us]-resolution timing tools. **Would you mind to re-run and benchmark your proposal** on your machine so as to make the concept quantitatively comparable with the other approach, given better performance is the target?